# How to switch to the first photo in a category swiperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

https://jsfiddle.net/Gorotto/mtcjxyg3/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var swiperGallerySlider = new Swiper('.gallery-slider', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    speed: 500,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerGroup: 3,
    observer: true,
    // slideToClickedSlide: true,
    observeParents: true,
    init: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.gallery__next',
      prevEl: '.gallery__prev',
    },
  });

  $('.toggle-wrap').attr("data-class", $('.gallery-slider .swiper-slide-active').data('type'));

  var updatetype = function(index) {
    $('.toggle-wrap').attr("data-class", $('.swiper-slide-active').data('type'));
    return false;
  };

  swiperGallerySlider.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', function(realIndex) {
    updatetype();

  });

});
```

```css
.gallery-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[data-class=exterior] .toggle-btn:first-of-type {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}

[data-class=interior] .toggle-btn:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.8/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-wrap current"><span class="toggle-btn">Экстерьер</span><span class="toggle-btn" id="ter">Интерьер</span></div>
<div class="gallery-slider swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534804101463-987ef0c79d54?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1950&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534804101463-987ef0c79d54?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1950&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475415949483-6d6590e8d475?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526931072202-5ba10196c45d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498409414967-907800891615?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=963&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567016376408-0226e4d0c1ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567016376408-0226e4d0c1ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521334884684-d80222895322?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583847268964-b28dc8f51f92?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601628828688-632f38a5a7d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=911&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521334884684-d80222895322?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-nav">
  <div class="gallery__prev">prev</div>
  <div class="gallery__next">next</div>
</div>
```

There is a slider in it, there are 2 categories of pictures, some of them will have the attribute Exterior, others will have Interior (perhaps there is an option to divide them differently than to set an attribute for each picture). Scrolling to photos of another category, we change the highlight at the point.

Question: How to scroll to the first photo of the corresponding category by clicking on an item. Couldn't bind SlideTo and attribute.

Comment: What is the item that you can click on?

Comment: @emiel-zuurbier 
you can see it better here https://codepen.io/Gorotto/pen/XWpBYNY
when paging forward, the state of y changes Exterior/Interior.
It is necessary that when you click on these names, the slider rewinds to the corresponding photo

Comment: I guess the issue was that it was in russian, which I can't read. But now I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use an element that supports native clicks like a `<a>` or `<button>`. In this case I've used a `<button>` as the functionality does not require any navigation.

Give the `button` a `value` attribute. The value of this attribute should be the `type` the button represents.

Start by listening for the `click` event on the `.toggle-btn` elements. When clicked, get the `value` from the button. Then filter the slides so that we only have the elements with the `data-type="..."` based on the button we clicked.

Then get the first element from that filtered list. Get the index of that element in the list of all the slides and slide to the index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const $slides = $('.swiper-slide');

  var swiperGallerySlider = new Swiper('.gallery-slider', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    speed: 500,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerGroup: 3,
    observer: true,
    // slideToClickedSlide: true,
    observeParents: true,
    init: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.gallery__next',
      prevEl: '.gallery__prev',
    },
  });

  $('.toggle-wrap').attr("data-class", $('.gallery-slider .swiper-slide-active').data('type'));

  var updatetype = function(index) {
    $('.toggle-wrap').attr("data-class", $('.swiper-slide-active').data('type'));
    return false;
  };

  swiperGallerySlider.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', function(realIndex) {
    updatetype();
  });
  
  $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    const $this = $(this);
    
    // Get the value of the button that has been clicked.
    const type = $this.val();
    
    // Get only the slides with a specific data-type.
    const $filteredSlides = $slides.filter(`[data-type="${type}"]`);
    
    // Get the first slide with that type.
    const $firstSlide = $filteredSlides.first();
    
    // Get the index of the first slide.
    const firstSlideIndex = $slides.index($firstSlide);
    
    // Slide to the index.
    swiperGallerySlider.slideTo(firstSlideIndex);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[data-class=exterior] .toggle-btn:first-of-type {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}

[data-class=interior] .toggle-btn:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.8/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-wrap current"><button class="toggle-btn" value="exterior">Экстерьер</button><button class="toggle-btn" id="ter" value="interior">Интерьер</button></div>
<div class="gallery-slider swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534804101463-987ef0c79d54?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1950&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534804101463-987ef0c79d54?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1950&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475415949483-6d6590e8d475?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526931072202-5ba10196c45d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="exterior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498409414967-907800891615?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=963&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567016376408-0226e4d0c1ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567016376408-0226e4d0c1ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521334884684-d80222895322?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583847268964-b28dc8f51f92?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601628828688-632f38a5a7d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=911&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521334884684-d80222895322?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="swiper-slide" data-type="interior"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=867&amp;q=80" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-nav">
  <div class="gallery__prev">prev</div>
  <div class="gallery__next">next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this works great.
The slider has a 2-column mode. When there are 6 pictures in a slide and 5 of them are of the same type, when you move to the next slide using the prev / next buttons, the "toggle-wrap" block has an incorrect attribute. The example shows this

Comment: You're welcome. That sounds like a new question. Create a new question so we can help you out.

Comment: Hi, I have created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297948/correct-definition-of-the-swiper-attribute-when-swiping